# Installing package with poetry in github actions installs dependencies but not my project

Tags: python, pytest, github-actions, python-poetry

I'm switching a python project over to poetry for dependency and packaging management, and am running into issues getting my github actions unit tests working. I believe the issue is that poetry is not actually installing my package. When I run `poetry install` locally, after it installs dependencies it shows that it installs the current project with the line:

```
Installing the current project: monaco (0.1.0)
```

However when I run `poetry install` in github actions, it installs the dependencies but never shows that line where it installed the current project. [Here's the github test log for context](https://github.com/scottshambaugh/monaco/runs/3785614231), look under the "Install library" step. Then, when I try to run tests after that, they fail because they can't find the package:

```
ImportError while importing test module '/home/runner/work/monaco/monaco/tests/test_MCCase.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.7/x64/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_MCCase.py:4: in <module>
    from monaco.MCCase import MCCase
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'monaco'
```

This is my first time using poetry, so it's likely that I'm doing something silly somewhere. But I've spent the last couple hours trying to figure it out and have gotten nowhere. Any help would be much appreciated!

My unit_tests.yml file looks like this:

```
name: Unit Tests
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - develop
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
      - develop

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Set up python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.9

      - name: Install Poetry
        uses: snok/install-poetry@v1

      - name: Install library
        run: poetry install

      - name: Run tests
        run: |
          poetry run python -m pytest
```

Comment: I honestly don’t understand the point of all these new tools. For ex. in my case `setup.py` works well enough in my projects. I have no idea what the point of a new tool like poetry is. No one explains it at all either - they’re just like, here’s an example of using poetry, do with it what you will. I’m like, no thanks, what I got works well enough for me. Maybe I’m missing something i suppose.

Comment: This is my first time packaging a project, so I tried to follow recent ‘best practices’ advice. If this doesn’t work I’ll definitely fall back to what does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I'm an idiot, I had just renamed my project from "Monaco" to "monaco", but forgot to update the module directory name to lowercase. Fixing that fixed my issue.

Comment: LOL don't be too harsh on yourself, we've ALL been there at least once :)

Comment: In my defense, inconsistent case sensitivity can be a pernicious bug to track down since it breaks in weird places.