# Installing package with poetry in gitlab ci installs dependencies but not my package

Tags: gitlab-ci, pep8, python-poetry

I have an interesting situation where poetry works as expected locally (installing both the dependencies and my package), but in the GitLab CI step (where I use the same poetry version `1.1.11` and python version `3.8`) only the dependencies are installed and not my package.

After some debugging, I found out that the issue might be that the name of my package does not follow the python naming convention: it contains capitalized characters `ExampleProject`.
After renaming the `ExampleProject` to no-caps version `exampleproject`, the poetry in GitLab CI would instal it as expected. The problem is I can not reproduce this behaviour locally! Using poetry versions `1.1.11` and `1.1.12`, locally my package gets installed independently of the caps in the package name and I see:

```
Installing the current project: ExampleProject (0.1.0)
```

So the question is, why doesn't poetry work the same way in GitLab CI? Any tips on further debugging this issue would be appreciated.

This seems to happen in the [GitHub Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69430109/installing-package-with-poetry-in-github-actions-installs-dependencies-but-not-m) also, but the author of that question did not dive deeper into reproducibility and why this happens.

`.gitlab-ci.yml` snippet:

```
test-step:
  stage: test
  image: python:3.8.5
  before_script:
    - pip3 install poetry
    - python3 -m poetry install
```

`pyproject.toml` snippet:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "ExampleProject"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "..."
authors = ["John Doe <jd@johndoe.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "~3.8"
numpy = "1.21.3"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

## Official solution

After digging through the poetry issues, I learned that the non-conventional package names are currently not [officially supported](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1538). However, there is a simple solution by [explicitly including the package in the configuration](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#packages) file `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "ExampleProject"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "..."
authors = ["John Doe <jd@johndoe.com>"]
packages = [
    {include = "ExampleProject"}
]
```

This would make it work in GitLab CI or GitHub Actions. There is also a [feature request](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4326) for changing this behaviour and allowing capitalization in package names.

But my question still remains: why does it work for me locally?

Comment: One case i can think of is when you installed your older poetry, dependencies were installed with it. When you installed new poetry some old dependencies might be used. I would suggest try creating a new virtual env and install new poetry version `1.1.11` locally and then try.

Comment: @Origin good point, however I already tried a fresh terminal without venvs, created new directory and minimal example from scratch, and still the poetry works locally without issues and installs the package with capitalized chars in the name.

Comment: I guess you are using locally windows. This is case-insensitive, so `ExampleProject`, `exampleproject`, `ExAmPleProJeCT` are all the same. Your CI/CD runs under a case sensitive OS, so poetry cannot find the correct folder.

Comment: @finswimmer cool idea but no. I am using macOS 11.6.1. I have reproduced this with multiple python3 versions and poetry versions locally. And in GitLab CI I have tried with a couple of different python3.8 images. It made no difference.

Comment: @dsalaj Can u just check in all the cases u tried in gitlab ci whether `ExampleProject` and `exampleproject` are treated as different. Poetry wont install the package it its present. So as @finswimmer pointed out it could be the reason